# Configuring portainer(-ce) from docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, configuration, local, portainer

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    [...]
    portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer-ce
        ports:
            - "10280:9000"
        volumes:
            - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
            - "./portainer:/data"
        restart: unless-stopped

        command: --admin-password $$2b$$05$$XJA5Fr6FGLsptH8mb2/L2uwH2mXGDJkfbTUkpuFEnSkpWY9D2EKCO
    [...]
```

(the "[...]" just is for other services which aren't related to the problem)

I configured the admin password with `command: --admin-password [bcryptHash]` but how do I configure it to use the local / "volumed" docker instance / socket from docker-compose and not from the web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this command

> command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Comment: Thanks! Also, it doesn't name it `local` but `primary` like it would normally but that's not bad

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference to this call for the `-H` flag here: https://docs.portainer.io/v/ce-2.6/advanced/reverse-proxy/traefik

This contains a full docker-compose file example that sets up a reverse proxy for portainer using traefik. The relevant section is:

```yaml
version: "3.3"
  services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:2.6.3
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data

volumes:
  portainer_data:
```

From the official docker documentation site, there is a link to the [awesome-compose repo](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/blob/master/portainer/docker-compose.yaml) that also has a docker-compose file example for portainer.

So from this document, it would appear that both the volume map for the socket and the command line flag are required.